# is there an easy way to add a progress bar/counter where I can add a line to increment it every so often - Not Timed

Tags: python, progress-bar

I have a script that is basically complete. I'd like to add some sort of a progress bar to it, instead of printing out each step as it passes by

is there anything that will let me do this.

setup a progress widget/counter/loop
give it a command function to increment

do some script
add the code to advance/increment the progress bar
do some more script
add the code to advance/increment the progress bar
do some more script
add the code to advance/increment the progress bar
do some more script
add the code to advance/increment the progress bar

also, can you please give me an example of some sort
I've looked at 3 or 4 different "progress bar" type libraries, and none give an example of doing it this way
all of the examples I seem to find want to do it by time or by byte size for downloading files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of progress bars in PIP, I recommend [ezprogress](https://pypi.org/project/ezprogress/) if you run python3.

```py
from ezprogress.progressbar import ProgressBar
import time

# Number of steps in your total script
steps_needed = 100
current_step = 0

# setup progress bar
pb = ProgressBar(steps_needed, bar_length=100)
pb.start()


# Do what your script wants
...

# Increment counter
current_step += 1
pb.update(current_step)

# Do what your script wants
...


# When you are done you can force the progress bar to finish
PB.finished()
```

The progress bar did not support turning off time estimation, however it is now possible in the newest version, just upgrade from PIP.

To turn off time estimation the progress bar just needs to be started with the parameter `no_time=True` like in the code below:

```
pb = ProgressBar(steps_needed, bar_length=100, no_time=True)
```

Comment: Thats simple enough... Thanks

Comment: how do I get rid of the estimated time to completion? I dont need that to show as its Highly inaccurate with what I am doing

Comment: I now answered that as an edit to my original answer. If it solved your issue it would be great if you mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/Joklost/ezprogress.git doesnt work for me
what am I missing to make that work from a command line window

just tells me sudo not found

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to install pip packages on windows. On Monday the pip package will be updated on the official repository, and you can update it the way you installed it in the first place.

Comment: @soundtechscott the updated progress-bar is now in pip, so just install the update and the `no_time` parameter will work.

Answer (score 0):

create your progressbar.py module

```
import sys
import copy
currentProgressCnt = 0
progressCntMax     = 0  # 
progressBarWidth   = 50 # in chars
scaleFctr          = 0.0
tasksToDo          = []
class ProgressIndicator:
    def showProgress(self):
        global progressCntMax
        global currentProgressCnt
        cr                 = "\r"
        progressChar       = '#'
        fillChar           = '.'
        progressBarDone = currentProgressCnt*progressChar*scaleFctr
        progressBarRemain = fillChar*(progressCntMax - currentProgressCnt)*scaleFctr
        percent = str(int((float(currentProgressCnt)/float(progressCntMax))*100)) + " % completed "
        taskId = '(' + tasksToDo[currentProgressCnt - 1] + ') '
        quote = str(currentProgressCnt) + '/' + str(progressCntMax) + ' '
        sys.stdout.write(cr + progressBarDone + progressBarRemain + ' ' + percent + taskId + quote)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if currentProgressCnt == progressCntMax:
            print
    def incProgress(self):
        global currentProgressCnt
        currentProgressCnt += 1

    def setLastStep(self, size):
        global progressCntMax, scaleFctr
        progressCntMax = size
        scaleFctr = progressBarWidth / progressCntMax
    def setTaskList(self, taskList):
        global tasksToDo
        tasksToDo = copy.copy(taskList)
        self.setLastStep(len(tasksToDo))
```

in main, use the ProgressIndicator class like this:

```
from progressbar import ProgressIndicator
import time 
import datetime
#########################################
###              MAIN                 ###
###           SIMULATION              ###       
#########################################

# your procedure list you have to run
toDoList = ['proc1', 'proc2', 'proc3', 'proc1', 'proc4', 'proc5', 
            'proc6', 'proc7', 'proc21', 'proc32', 'proc43', 'proc51',
            'proc4', 'proc65', 'proc76', 'proc87']
progressLine = ProgressIndicator() # create your indicator
progressLine.setTaskList(toDoList) # set params

# your main work
i = 0; lastTask = len(toDoList)
# log the start
startTime = str(datetime.datetime.now())
print ( startTime + " main started")
while i <  lastTask:
    # run your task list here
    time.sleep(1) # simulating your toDoList[i]() run
    i += 1
    progressLine.incProgress()   # use when task done, incrase progress 
    progressLine.showProgress()  # use for update display
# work is done, log the end
endTime = str(datetime.datetime.now())
print ( endTime + " main finished")
```